# Как в Mockito проверять на исключения?

Tags: java, исключения, junit, mockito

Есть метод

```
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteMessage(@PathVariable Long id) {
    if (!messageService.delete(id)) {
        throw  new DataNotFoundException("Data with id=" + id + " not found.");
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

И тест к нему

```
@Test
public void deleteMessageIfNotFoundThenException() {
    //prepare
    when(messageController.deleteMessage(2L)).thenThrow(DataNotFoundException.class);
    //testing
    ResponseEntity<?> failedDelete = messageController.deleteMessage(2L);
    //validate
    verify(messageController).deleteMessage(2L);
}
```

Ну пойму как правильно проверять, тест не проходит.

И DataNotFoundException

```
public class DataNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public DataNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете указать ожидаемое исключение в аннотации теста

```
@Test(expected = DataNotFoundException.class)
public void deleteMessageIfNotFoundThenException() {
    //prepare
    when(messageController.deleteMessage(2L)).thenThrow(DataNotFoundException.class);
    //testing
    ResponseEntity<?> failedDelete = messageController.deleteMessage(2L);
}
```

Если вы хотите сохранить BDD-стиль теста, можете воспользоваться библиотекой [catch-exception](https://github.com/Codearte/catch-exception). Код будет примерно такой:

```
verifyException(messageController, IndexOutOfBoundsException.class).deleteMessage(2L);
```

или такой, если вы хотите проверить дополнительно свойства исключения.

```
when(messageController).deleteMessage(2L);
then(caughtException())
    .isInstanceOf(DataNotFoundException.class)
    .hasMessageContaining("your message here");
```

Comment: А если так же проверять на сообщение которое выбрасывает?

Comment: @SergeiR, обновил ответ.

Comment: Удивительно, но я все равно получаю ответ test failed ....exception.DataNotFoundException: Data with id=2 not found.

Comment: @SergeiR даже с указанием expected = DataNotFoundException.class ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator Да. .isInstanceOf(DataNotFoundException.class)

Comment: @SergeiR нет, я про `@Test(expected = DataNotFoundException.class)`. Покажите обновленный код, пожалуйста

Comment: @SeniorAutomator Спасибо, проглядел я этот момент.

Comment: Пробовал .hasMessageContaining и .hasMessage с произвольным текстом, всегда тест проходит. Хотя не должен.

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки полученного сообщения в исключениях можно использовать try-catch блок:

```
    @Test
public void deleteMessageIfNotFoundThenException() {
    //prepare
    long id = 2L;
    try{
        messageController.deleteMessage(id)
    } catch (DataNotFoundException e) {
        if (e.getMessage().equals("Data with id=" + id + " not found.") {
        //some message or log or output
        return;
        }
    }
    Assert.fail();
}
```

Comment: Не буду ставить "-", но вопрос о другом - почему не проходит тест.